# SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage java.io.InvalidClassException: com.vaadin.server.VaadinServletRequest; no valid constructor

Tags: java, tomcat8, vaadin7, mariadb-10.4

I created the war file of a web application and deployed on tomcat and started the tomcat server.
server is started successfully but I can see below exception in catalina.out file.

SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage

java.io.InvalidClassException: com.vaadin.server.VaadinServletRequest; no valid constructor
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(ObjectStreamClass.java:169)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:885)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2160)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2404)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2186)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:502)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:460)

Anybody has faced this issue? Your inputs/Solutions is much appreciated..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I hope you found a solution by now, but my first thought would be to check whether there were any errors during the war creation.